# iOS - CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Is there a way to find out what type of device it is that I have scanned?

After iOS 7?

For instance, APPLE, DELL, LENOVO, ect.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see if the device you have connected to implements the [Device Information](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.service.device_information.xml) service. If it does then you can read the [Manufacturer Name characteristic](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.manufacturer_name_string.xml).

There is no way of determining this information without actually connecting to the peripheral.

Answer (score 0):

This would only be possible if the product developer included this in the advertisement data or within a GATT service.

You can observe advertisement data when `CBCentralManager` discovers peripherals, [see documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/1518937-centralmanager?preferredLanguage=occ).

Information like this might be found under the [CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/advertisement_data_retrieval_keys) dictionary key.

Comment: Manufacturer Data is data provided by the manufacturer (usually for their own use) rather than data about the manufacturer. It is rarely their name.